# Signature Capture in Web Application

Tags: android, ios, ipad, web-applications

We have a web application which will be browsed from Android Tablet/iPad. We are trying to get the signature from the user. What is the best way to capture the signature?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a web application like you say, you can utilize Thomas J. Bradley's [Signature Pad jQuery Plugin](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad) to do the trick, which will record the signature in a JSON structure for later retrieval.

Comment: Hello anterec,

  I've gone through this documentation and i have some questions...

http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad#require-drawn

1) The document says that Android<3.0 has some problems with converting the image from client side

2) Converting the image from server side, they have only C# to JPEG, PNG or GIF. But we are using vb.net

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello esqew,,,,, sorry wrong name in my previous comment...